# Publish a SharePoint Article Page Without Changing Modified By Value

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

I am changing the content type of pages using CSOM and would like to preserve the modified by field as it is. The issue is I can set the modified by value to original value, but as soon as I publish the page it changes.

```
        var listItem = pagesLibrary.GetItemById(record.ListItemID);


        /// Get the page from the Pages library.
        Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File page = listItem.File;

        /// Load the document.
        clientContext.Load(page);

        //Load the requested list item
        clientContext.Load(listItem,
                         item => item["Title"],
                         item => item["Author"],
                         item => item["Editor"],
                         item => item["Created"],
                         item => item["Modified"],
                         item => item["_ModerationStatus"]);

        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();  

        listItem["Author"] = newAuthorFieldUserValue;        

        listItem["Editor"] = editorUserValue;

        listItem.Update();

        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        clientContext.Load(page);
        listItem.File.Publish("Published");
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With CSOM package 16.1.5626.1200 list item has SystemUpdate method.No need to checkout the page when updating pages and when updating they are not getting unpublished as well.

https://dev.office.com/blogs/new-sharepoint-csom-version-released-for-Office-365-august-2016-updated